# How to access an array that comes from a promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I have performed this bit of code:

```
async function getFilteredResults(weather, type, activity) {
 const response = await fetch("locations.json", {});
 const json = await response.json();

 return json.filter(
  (obj) => obj.TempRating == weather && obj.Category == activity && obj.Location == type
 );
}
```

And it returns this in the console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
 [[Prototype]]: Promise
 [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
 [[PromiseResult]]: Array(1)0: 
  {HolidayReference: 9, HotelName: 'Desert Dreams', City: 'Dubai', Continent: 'Asia', Country: 'U.A.E', …}length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

How do I then access the values of this array in my script? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an async function and that means your function returns a promise. The result of `return json.filter(/* ... */)` is actually a promise.

```js
async function getFilteredResults(weather, type, activity) {
 const response = await fetch("locations.json", {});
 const json = await response.json();

 // this return value is actually a promise since it comes from an async function
 return json.filter(
  (obj) => obj.TempRating == weather && obj.Category == activity && obj.Location == type
 );
}
```

You need to write

```js
getFilteredResults(/* ... */).then(val => {
  // here you will have access to that array
})
```

Comment: This is an ***often***-repeated duplicate quesiton. Please don't post answers to obvious duplicates. Instead, vote to close, pointing to the earlier established question(s).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Alright no problem